# Where are the references in this paper?

Tags: specific-reference, textbook-erratum

I do not know if this is the correct place to ask this but I do not know where else to ask. This paper https://doi.org/10.1016/0920-5632(90)90647-D has 15 references at the end. However, in the text there are citations to articles that are not referenced. For example at the end of page 66 there is the citation [26, 27, 22]. What is going on?

Comment: The easiest explanation is sloppy editing in a proceedings article. Or somewhere in the process the last few pages with all the references slipped off the table and were lost (1990 makes a paper submission quite plausible). And, as a proceedings, the authors didn't look too closely at the galley proofs (if they were even offered).

Comment: That is a bizarre case indeed. Honestly, I would just write to the author and see what he says.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics as a natural science.